# Rails + StimulusJS dynamically created select menu doesn't work

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, stimulusjs

I'm dynamically adding fields to my form. In case of a standard text field it works fine with Rails + StimulusJS with an `<template>` element.

I'm using MaterializeCSS for styling and if I try to do the same thing with a select menu, it breaks and it seems the innerHTML I get back in my JS code doesn't match the code inside the template-tag. So I decided to use a div instead which I duplicate.

The view code (the relevant part):

```
<div data-nested-form-target="template">
   <%= f.fields_for :stations, department.stations.build, child_index: "NEW_RECORD" do |station| %>
     <%= render "admin/departments/stations/station_fields", f: station %>
   <% end %>
```

This is the template I duplicte in my Stimulus controller.

This is what the first (and working) select menu looks like in HTML:

[image]

So the next step was to change the ID'S of the `<ul>` and the two `<li>` elements + the `data-target` element to target the right select menu.

What I ended up was this JS-Code, which is indeed adding a second select menu with the right styles, but it is not clickable and doesn't show options, despite they exist in the HTML markup and the ID's differ from the first one:

```
add_association(event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        let random_id = this.generate_random_id()
        let content = this.templateTarget.cloneNode(true)
        content.getElementsByTagName("ul").item(0).setAttribute("id", random_id)
        content.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-trigger").item(0).setAttribute("data-target", random_id)
        let list_elements = Array.from(content.getElementsByTagName("ul").item(0).querySelectorAll("li"))
        list_elements.forEach((item) => {
            let rnd = this.generate_random_id()
            item.setAttribute("id", rnd)
        })
        let html = content.innerHTML.replace(/NEW_RECORD/g, new Date().getTime())
        this.linksTarget.insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin", html)
        console.log(html)
        let collection = this.basicTarget.getElementsByClassName("nested-fields")
        let element = collection[collection.length - 1].getElementsByClassName("animate__animated")[0]
        element.classList.add(this.fadeInClass)
    }
```

Now it looks like this and I can't figure out how to make this thing working:

[image]

Comment: Can you post the generated HTML after the second select box has been added?

Answer (score 0):

We're using the same stack (Rails, Stimulus.js, Materialize) with no problem. One thing you have to do after updating the select is re-initialize the Materialize select. For example, this is a general purpose nested select controller in which different sub-selects become active based on the parent select:

```
import { Controller } from 'stimulus';
import Materialize from 'materialize-css';

export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = [
    'childSelect',
  ]

  parentSelectChanged (e) {
    const selectedParentMenu = e.target.value;

    this.childSelectTargets.forEach(selectElement => {
      if (selectElement.dataset.parentMenuName === selectedParentMenu) {
        selectElement.disabled = false;
        selectElement.value = '';
      } else {
        selectElement.disabled = true;
      }
      Materialize.FormSelect.init(selectElement);
    });
  }
}
```

And here is the corresponding Haml:

```
.input-field.col
  = select_tag :category,
    options_for_select(grouped_conditions.keys.sort, selected_parent_menu_name),
    include_blank: 'Select One...',
    data: { action: 'nested-select#parentSelectChanged' }

.input-field.col.hide-disabled
  - grouped_conditions.each do |parent_menu_name, child_conditions|
    = f.select :condition_id,
      options_for_select(child_conditions.sort_by(&:menu_name).map{ |tc| [tc.menu_name, tc.id] }, selected_condition_id),
      { include_blank: 'Select One...' },
      disabled: selected_parent_menu_name != parent_menu_name,
      data: { 'nested-select-target' => 'childSelect', 'parent-menu-name' => parent_menu_name }
    = f.label :condition_id
```

Comment: Yeah I thought something like re-initializing could fix it, I'll try the way you did it. Honestly, my next project won't use Materialize :D